# Fast oriented graphs in bokeh

Tags: python, networkx, bokeh

To plot a graph (`networkx.DiGraph`), I am using the following code (looping over all edges):

```
arrow = Arrow(end=OpenHead(line_color=color, line_width=12, size=14),
                  y_start=pos[from_node][1],
                  x_start=pos[from_node][0],
                  x_end=pos[to_node][0],
                  y_end=pos[to_node][1],
                  line_color=color, line_width=12)
plot.add_layout(arrow)
```

I would like to use `multi_line` instead of this, but there is no way how to add arrows. Or is there any?

Answer (score 1):

I once use networkx to genearte a graph with 'Arrow', actually not a real arrow, but can be treated like one:[image]

The codes that genearate this is to implement a Kosaraju–Sharir algorithm (find strongly connected components); The main codes is as following:

```
def generate_G():
    G = defaultdict(set)
    G['a'] = {'b', 'c'}
    G['b'] = {'d', 'e', 'i'}
    G['c'] = {'d'}
    G['d'] = {'a', 'h'}
    G['e'] = {'f'}
    G['f'] = {'g'}
    G['g'] = {'e', 'h'}
    G['h'] = {'i'}
    G['i'] = {'h'}
    return G

def draw_G(raw_G):
    import networkx as nx
    import matplotlib
    # generate postscript output by default from http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend
    matplotlib.use('PS')
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import pylab
    G = nx.DiGraph()
    G.add_nodes_from(raw_G.keys())
    G.add_edges_from([(u, v) for u in raw_G for v in raw_G[u]], weight=1)
    pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
    edge_labels = dict([((u, v,), d['weight'])
                    for u, v, d in G.edges(data=True)])
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, alpha=0.3)
    nx.draw(G, pos=pos, node_size=250, with_labels=True, )
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.savefig("kosaraju.png")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    raw_G = generate_G()
    draw_G(raw_G)
```

The complete codes could be found at my github, if you're interested: https://github.com/albertmenglongli/Algorithms/blob/master/PythonAlgrithoms/kosaraju.py, and the image generated is here: https://github.com/albertmenglongli/Algorithms/blob/master/PythonAlgrithoms/kosaraju.png

I tried to implement many algrothims but in a more engineering way, if anyone who is interested.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see [in tutorials](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html) and [github code](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/53cd93bea4168f87d296ad8a0b9bcd7d18e886ae/bokeh/models/glyphs.py), the `multi_line` function wasn't intended to be a graph drawing function, and should be used only for linear data plot, just with more than one data source.

However, that function accepts [`LineProps`](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/53cd93bea4168f87d296ad8a0b9bcd7d18e886ae/bokeh/core/property_mixins.py) object, so you can try out to adjust it to your needs. For now, [line options](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#line-properties) are:

- `line_color`
- `line_width`
- `line_alpha`
- **`line_join`**
- `line_cap`
- `line_dash`
- `line_dash_offset`

I suggest you to try out the `line_join` property, with possible values:

- 'miter' [image]
- 'round' [image]
- 'bevel' [image]

So the method could be something like this:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

p = figure(plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
p.multi_line(xs=[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]], ys=[[6, 7, 2], [4, 5, 7]],
             color=['red','green'], line_join='miter')
show(p)
```

Complete reference for `bokeh.plotting` can be found [here](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/plotting.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, it simply does not work. I cannot see any arrows there. Would you mind to share your output from your code, please?

Comment: @KarelMacek did you try all the variants?

Comment: from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

p = figure(plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
p.multi_line(xs=[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]], ys=[[6, 7, 2], [4, 5, 7]],
             color=['red','green'], line_join='miter')
show(p)